# Render only showing color on perimeter of walls/object

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine, color

[image]

I finished modeling and coloring this room about a month ago, but upon opening and rendering (in Eevee) it today, the purple and blue colors on the wall don't show up in the render the same way as they do in the material preview. Is there any way to fix this/why this is? The trim and wall are one object but colored differently just by selecting different faces. I have included the project file as well.

Thanks!

[Link to project file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LawymKchOmB4gg3NKRiwyJ7m-E3rGM9x/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: The render suggests that there are some objects (placeholders from an earlier version, perhaps?) in the Outliner that are hidden in viewport but still visible in render.  The camera icon needs to be ticked for them.

Comment: @AllenSimpson Awesome, that was totally it! Had an extra wall model. Thanks!!